# 3 circles of radii 1,2 and 3 and centers A, B and C respectively, touch each other.......

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, triangles, circles, conic-sections

> 3 circles of radii 1,2 and 3 and centers A, B and C respectively, touch each other. Another circle whose center is P touches all 3 externally and has radius $r$. Also $\angle PAB=\theta$ and $\angle PAC=\alpha$. Prove that
>
> $\cos \theta= \frac{3-r}{3(1+r)}$
>
> $\cos \alpha = \frac{2-r}{2(1+r)}$
>
> $r=\frac {6}{23}$

I imagine the circle $P$ to be in the center of the three circles. The $\Delta ABC$ is a right angled at A, so $\theta+\alpha = 90$

I know the lengths $PA, PB$ and $PC$ in terms of $r$

All the angles of the triangle are also well known.

If we consider $\Delta ABP$, then

$$\cos \theta = \frac{PA^2+AB^2-PB^2}{2PA.PB}$$

Here

$$PA=1+r$$
$$AB=3$$
$$PB=2+r$$

so
$$\cos \theta = \frac{9+(1+r^2)-(2+r)^2}{(2)(3)(1+r)}$$

which ends up being 1. I feel my approach is fundamentally wrong, so please correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be $$\cos\theta=\frac{9+(1+r)^2-(2+r)^2}{2\cdot3\cdot(1+r)}=\frac{6-2r}{6(1+r)}=\frac{3-r}{3(1+r)}.$$
Also, $$\cos\alpha=\frac{16+(1+r)^2-(3+r)^2}{2\cdot4\cdot(1+r)}=\frac{2-r}{2(1+r)}$$ and since $$\alpha+\theta=90^{\circ},$$ we obtain: 
$$\left(\frac{3-r}{3(1+r)}\right)^2+\left(\frac{2-r}{2(1+r)}\right)^2=1$$ or
$$4(9-6r+r^2)+9(4-4r+r^2)=36(1+2r+r^2)$$ or
$$(r+6)(23r-6)=0,$$ which gives $$r=\frac{6}{23}.$$

Comment: Okay, that was a calculation problem. Can you explain how to find the radius though?